# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.99

Tags: android, android-studio

> Error:Could not find
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.99. Searched in the
>   following locations:
>       file:/D:/Android_SDK/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.pom
>       file:/D:/Android_SDK/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.jar
>       file:/D:/Android_SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.pom
>       file:/D:/Android_SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.jar
>       file:/D:/Android_SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.pom
>       file:/D:/Android_SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.jar
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.pom
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.jar
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.pom
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.jar
>       https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.pom
>       https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.jar
>       https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.pom
>       https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.99/play-services-location-11.6.99.jar

**Required by:**
    project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.0

Comment: You should add a question to your question ... and your code.

Comment: replace `11.6,99` to `11.6.0` in your gradle file playservice dependency

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, use the older version in this way

```
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5'
```

Problem is offically from OneSignal, listed also here
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/395

Comment: @desertnaut This solves the problem (or question, call it whatever you want...). I thought that this should be the primary target here. I can not give a more "precise" answer since library involved (OneSignal) is not developed by me, and this is why I also quoted them in the answer and the link to issue on GitHub.

Comment: @desertnaut Don't worry, happy to clarify when is necessary, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but I got the same error, here is some more info:
My project has been absolutely fine so far. However, when I fired up my Android studio today, gradle refresh failed. Out of nowhere a dependency is not found. I do not include it in any compile ' ' statement, it seems to be required by OneSignal, as written in the log. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version is com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2. Do this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
```

or you can also do

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is offically from OneSignal latest version 3.7.0, listed also here https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/395.
if you have mentioned one signal in your project like:

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'
```

try to change it to

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5'
```